How To Handle Loading Between Page Changes in NextJS 14 (app router)?
I'm migrating my Next.js project from version 12 to 14 and encountered an issue with a loading component that used to work perfectly. Now, I'm getting the following error:
Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted
src\components\Loading.tsx (10:26) @ useRouter

This is the relevant code for my Loading component, which listens to route changes:
path: src/component/Loading.tsx
'use client'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import styles from './Loading.module.scss'

const Loading = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleStart = () => setLoading(true)
        const handleComplete = () => setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000)

        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
        router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleComplete)
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete)

        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
            router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleComplete)
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete)
        }
    })

    return loading && <div className={styles.loading} />
}

export default Loading

I have the Loading component inside the RootLayout like this:
path: src/app/layout.tsx
import Loading from '@/components/Loading'

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
    return (
        <html lang='en'>
            <body suppressHydrationWarning>
                <Loading />
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

In Next.js 12, this setup worked fine, but after upgrading to version 14, I kept getting the error mentioned above.
I suspect it has something to do with the app router and how Next.js 14 handles routing differently, but I haven't found a clear explanation or solution.

I though in Loading.tsx you're using the old nextjs loader package which is needs to be upgrade.

you can't use next/router in the app router. You have to use next/navigation. Docs

You do not need to use your custom logic by creating Loading component.
Next.js 14 App router provides loading.(tsx/jsx/js) file. You can create the file in the same level of your root layout (or whatever layout you want to wrap with the loading).
Next.js article on Loading UI
